# mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property -OneToOne annotation Error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

When i used the OneToOne hibernate annotation between Ordonnance and Consultation classes, that gave me that error :Unknown mappedBy in: com.onousc.entities.Consultation.ordonnance, referenced property unknown: com.onousc.entities.Ordonnance.consultation. Can anyone help me please . Thank you so much

// Class ordonnance

```
package com.onousc.entities;

import java.io.Serializable; import java.util.Collection; import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType; import javax.persistence.Entity; import javax.persistence.FetchType; import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue; import javax.persistence.GenerationType; import javax.persistence.Id; import javax.persistence.OneToMany; import javax.persistence.OneToOne; import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;

@Entity public class Ordonnance implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer idOrdo;
private Date dateOrdo;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="ordonnance",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Collection <LigneOrdonnance> LignesOrdo;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="ordonnance")
private Lettre lettre;

@OneToOne
private Consultation consultation;

public Ordonnance() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Ordonnance(Date dateOrdo) {
    super();
    this.dateOrdo = dateOrdo;
}


getters and setters..
}
```

//Class consultation 
    package com.onousc.entities;

```
import java.io.Serializable; import java.util.Collection; import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType; import javax.persistence.Entity; import javax.persistence.FetchType; import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue; import javax.persistence.GenerationType; import javax.persistence.Id; import javax.persistence.JoinColumn; import javax.persistence.JoinTable; import javax.persistence.ManyToMany; import javax.persistence.ManyToOne; import javax.persistence.OneToMany; import javax.persistence.OneToOne; import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;

@Entity public class Consultation implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer idConsult;
private Date dateConsult;
private String typeConsult;
private String motifConsult;
private String diagnostic;
private Boolean maladieChronique;
private String decision;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="consultation",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Collection <Examen> examens;
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="CONSULT_MAL")
private Collection <Maladie> maladies;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ID_PATIENT")
private Patient patient;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ID_MEDECIN")
private Medecin medecin;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="consultation")
private Ordonnance ordonnance;

public Consultation() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Consultation(Date dateConsult, String typeConsult,
        String motifConsult, String diagnostic, Boolean maladieChronique,
        String decision) {
    super();
    this.dateConsult = dateConsult;
    this.typeConsult = typeConsult;
    this.motifConsult = motifConsult;
    this.diagnostic = diagnostic;
    this.maladieChronique = maladieChronique;
    this.decision = decision;
}

getters and setters...
```

Comment: Use `mappedBy` only on one side of the relationship. The mappedBy will point to the "owning" entity, the entity that you want to have the foreignKey in it's table.

Comment: I did it , it doesnt give me this error ! But when i looked at the table, there is no foreign key ...

Comment: Which table did you look at?

Comment: In this post, i have inversed it, i have put the mappedBy in the class that don't have to contain the foreign key.But even though , there is foreign key in the concerned table..Moreover the error it doesn't show ..

Comment: I mean't there is no foreign key in the concerned table ( Ordonnance )

Comment: The Ordonnance Table needs to have the have the FK of the Consultation Table..

Comment: The thing is, you have the same mappedBy all over the place, which is confusing. I wouldn't put a mappedBy in a OneToOne relationship. If you have OneToOne from Consultation to Ordonnance, then I would expect the Consultation to hold the Ordonnance ID.

Comment: Normally i had to put in Ordonnance:@OneToOne(mappedBy="ordonnance")
 
    private Consultation consultation;                                                                           And in Consultation this:@OneToOne
 @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
   
    private Ordonnance ordonnance;

Comment: Because i want that the Ordonnance get the FK of Consultation Table. The error it doesnt show anymore, but there no changes in the Ordonnance table ( no FK)